# Hybrid app development: How to separate HTML5 + CSS3 + JS from PHP + SQL?

Tags: html, web-services, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid, multiplatform

I'm used to the full stack approach of developing where PHP can be used to create dynamic HTML and to handle SQL as well. However, I'm now considering creating an hybrid app that can be used across platforms.

So my questions are: should I separate the app into HTML5 + CSS3 + JS and PHP + SQL webservice? If so, how should the connection be done? with ajax requests to the webservice? Is this the correct approach?

Any suggestions, pointers or names of concepts that I should/could read regarding the topic are appreciated.

Comment: Using a Javascript framework can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a microservice approach. Using docker and some other container orchestration tool.

What I mean is that you could have a RESTful API written in php fetching data from a MySQL db (or any other db). Then simply write your front end app, using plain JavaScript, HTML and CSS, or a JavaScript framework (angularjs, react, etc). Then you could make your front end communicate with your back end through your API's endpoints.

The idea behind creating microservices or 12 factor apps, is to separate your apps in components or microservices. Then with some configuration and using the right tools you could have them all communicating between them. This way scaling is way easier, and maintaining the code even more.

Id recommend you read a bit more on JavaScript frameworks and microservices. There's a free course at Udacity on microservices using docker and kubernetes that I know will be extremely helpful. [Link here](https://www.udacity.com/course/scalable-microservices-with-kubernetes--ud615)

For front end JavaScript frameworks there's a ton of resources out there. Try CodeSchool free courses or codeacademy's.